# Overlaying circles on leaflet with d3 results in not positioned properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, leaflet

I want to overlay a `leaflet` map with `circles` through `d3`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3 Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map" style="width:600px; height:600px;">
    <script>
        var map = new L.Map("map", {
                center: [37.8, -96.9],
                zoom: 4
            })
            .addLayer(new L.TileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"));

        var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
            svgCircles = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

        d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/580256bbe4b0bcac9f7ffa43", function(error, myPoints) {
            if (error) throw error;


            myPoints.features.forEach(function(d) {
                d.LatLng = new L.LatLng(d.geometry.coordinates[1],
                    d.geometry.coordinates[0]);
            });

            var circles = svgCircles.selectAll("circle")
                .data(myPoints.features)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 100)
                .style("fill", "red")
                .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5);

            function update() {
                circles.attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).x;
                });
                circles.attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).y;
                });
            }

            map.on("viewreset", update);
            update();

        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The `circles` are added to `DOM`, but do not show up on leaflet. I suppose its because they are positioned wrong. 
Thats how it looks like:
[image: leafletmap]

How would I position them correct? Note: I dont want to use `map._initPathRoot();` to pick up the `svg-element` created by `leaflet`.

Comment: Examine your "cities" data.  The data in `d.geometry.coordinates[1],                   d.geometry.coordinates[0]` is **not** latitude and longitude.

Comment: @Mark I am so sorry, I linked to the wrong file! With that one it cannot work. I updated the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your radius on those circles is **way too large**.  You have thousands of points in your JSON file each with a radius of 100px and your map is only `600x600px`.

Second, it seems like you are attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/), but you are leaving out a key piece.  Mr. Bostock talks about how to calculate the bounding box of your features to place your SVG in the right position.  You've left this part out, so your SVG is being placed at `0,0` with a default size.

Following his tutorial with your data produces the following code.  **Note**, I limited your JSON data to only a few cities in the north-east.  I didn't want to find some place to host 6mb of JSON (you might want to think about cutting that file down to *only* US cities).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="width:600px; height:600px;"></div>
  <script>
    var map = new L.Map("map", {
        center: [37.8, -96.9],
        zoom: 4
      })
      .addLayer(new L.TileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"));

    var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
      svgCircles = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

    d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/580256bbe4b0bcac9f7ffa43", function(error, myPoints) {
      if (error) throw error;

      var transform = d3.geo.transform({
          point: projectPoint
        }),
        path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

      var bounds = path.bounds(myPoints),
        topLeft = bounds[0],
        bottomRight = bounds[1];

      myPoints.features.forEach(function(d) {
        d.LatLng = new L.LatLng(d.geometry.coordinates[1],
          d.geometry.coordinates[0]);
      });

      var circles = svgCircles.selectAll("circle")
        .data(myPoints.features)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5);

      // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
      function projectPoint(x, y) {
        var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
        this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
      }

      function update() {
        circles.attr("cx", function(d) {
          return map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).x;
        });
        circles.attr("cy", function(d) {
          return map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).y;
        });
        svg.attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
          .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
          .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
          .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

        svgCircles.attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");
      }

      map.on("viewreset", update);
      update();

    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**

Because I limited the data to a smaller subset of cities (those in NY and PA) the bounds are only calculated to what's in the data. [Here it is with all the cities in your JSON](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lqme891ee8rwDiXktY5L?p=preview) (wait a bit for it to load).

And a quick screenshot with all the data:

[image]

Comment: Nope, that does not do the trick. You are having the same problem I have. It only renders into one tile (the one under Toronto/Ottowa).

Comment: @Stophface, yes because I limited my cities to those in NY and PA.  The bounds are calculated to what's in the data.  Try it with all US cities

Comment: @Stophface, here it is with [all the data](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lqme891ee8rwDiXktY5L?p=preview).  You'll have to wait a while for it to load...

Comment: Ah, alright. It looked exactly like my problem they way it loaded. Thanks!